# How to present a view after removing a subview (log out button)?

Tags: ios, view, logout

I'm trying to log out from a button placed inside a subview (`SettingsViewController.h`). So I log in from `LogInViewController.h`, and go to my `HomeViewController.h`, in which I have a bar button item, Settings, which does the following code:

```
-(IBAction)settingsButton:(id)sender{
    SettingsViewController* settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
    settings.view.tag = 7; //This is to remove the settings from view in SettingsViewController.h
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:settings.view];
}
```

I wanted to add the view from `SettingsViewController.h` as a subview so that I can have a transparent background, with the `HomeViewController.h` view still visible behind the `SettingsViewController.h` view.

Now in `SettingsViewController.h`, I have the actual problem. I have a logout button and am trying to show the `LoginViewController.h` view after clicking that button. So here is the code in `SettingsViewController.h`:

```
-(IBAction)logoutButton:(id)sender{
    //I cleared all user preferences here
    //ex. [user loggedOut];
    LoginViewController *backToLoginScreen = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:backToLoginScreen animated:NO completion:nil];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:7] removeFromSuperview]; //This is supposed to remove the Settings view from the view, but if I try to log in again, the setting view will come up
}
```

So I'm guessing that once I called the `presentViewController`, it wouldn't remove any view, but I have no clue what to do to remove the Settings view. Help please? Thanks!

Comment: you are confusing views and view controllers. Can you please edit your question so that we understand what you want from your views and what you want from your view controllers?

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to make it clearer, please let me know if I should edit anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use  `popToViewController: animated:`  or `popViewControllerAnimated:` method to go back.Push adds a new instance of VC into the stack and hence after doing a push again you have two LoginViewController in the navigation stack.
2. Remove the view from superview before push/pop

Comment: Thanks, but I have a quick question, how would I call the LoginViewController that was previously stacked when I use `popToViewController: animated:`?

Comment: Use `popViewControllerAnimated:`